# Java: How does the compiler work for a specific method not to be found with an expression with the declared type as its superclass?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I understand that when invoking a method from an expression with its declared type as its superclass, that the method being invoked must also be implemented in  the superclass. I've looked all over and I do not understand why the compiler does this. *When an expression invokes a method, the compiler looks for an implementation of that method first in the subclass then its super class, and so on up to the Object class.* **So why would the compiler need to report that it can not find the implentation of a method in a superclass if it is already in a subclass?** For example:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Fruit a = new Apple();

        //Why can I not just do this?
        a.ripe();
    }
}

class Fruit
{
    public String eat()
    {
        return "I am being eaten!";
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit
{
    public String ripe()
    {
        return "I am ripe!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the spec says so.

The point is, you went out of your way to say that `a` is a variable of type `Fruit`, which means it can point at (in java-ese 'reference') any object whose type is Fruit or any subtype thereof.

Maybe later you want to do: `a = new Banana();` - and that would be fine.

Therefore, java won't let you do things with `a` unless the thing you want to do is a thing all `Fruit` objects can do.

Note that in:

`Fruit a = new Apple();`

you have a **variable** named `a` of type `Fruit`, an object (objects have no names), and the variable will be pointing at this object. You don't invoke methods on objects; you invoke them on expressions, and `a` is an expression representing the variable. `a.ripe()` means: "Take the variable 'a', and dereference it (follow the pointer). Then, at the object you find there, invoke the `ripe()` method.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, that Java won't let us do so. I also am aware about what a.ripe() means (although I mixed up the terminology). But it still doesn't answer my question. *How does the compiler work for it to not let us?* if what you are saying in the last sentence is correct

Comment: `a` is an expression. It is of type Fruit. Fruit does not have a ripe() method. Therefore the compiler says: "No such method". Simple as that.